# UICollectionView multiple line spacing values in a section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to set `minimumLineSpacing` to two different values within a collection view section. But the only method I can find is `collectionView(_ collectionView:, layout collectionViewLayout:, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section:)`, which dictates only one `minimumLineSpacing` value for each section.

Basically I have alternating cell A and B in the section. I want spacing between A and B to be 2, and B and the next A to be 10.

Answer (score 0):

try using `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt` which will make the spacing between cells in a section specified.
And implement `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt` for spacing between two sections.

Answer (score 0):

Ok base on my little experience, you can not achieve that feature the regular way like setting minimumLineSpacing for multiple times. The only way is **customization UICollectionViewLayout** to tell your UICollection how it should laid its child literally. Here is a clear tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/156794/custom-uicollectionviewlayout-tutorial-parallax